# Line break between <label> and .radio-inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I put a `<label>` above a couple of `.radio-inline`s, there is no line break between the `<label>` and the `.radio-inline`s (see http://jsfiddle.net/strL4v8r/).

What is the most elegant way to force that line break like it is seen between the `<input>`s and its `<label>`s?

Comment: Off topic: You shouldn't have multiple labels for an input, and you should use the `for` attribute for accessibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind additional markup:

```
<br>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/strL4v8r/1/)

Or, to eliminate the duplicate label scenario:

```
<div><strong>Number of choice</strong></div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/strL4v8r/2/)

A better option might be to use a fieldset with a legend:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Number of choice</legend>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    ...
```

You'd have to override the default Bootstrap styling, but it's better for accessibility.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/strL4v8r/4/) | [**Demo with styles**](http://jsfiddle.net/strL4v8r/5/)

Comment: The first two aren't anything I wouldn't have guesses by myself. The last one is an idea worth but definitely not intended by bootstrap. Hasn't bootstrap thought of that trivial use case of radio-buttons? I will wait one or two days and if nothing comes in I will accept your answer.

Comment: Bootstrap enhances HTML with CSS. It doesn't seek to entirely supplant good design. You're still responsible for creating the website. :-)